# Lua looking for version 5.2 when 5.1 is installed

Tags: lua

I am getting an error `module 'lsqlite3' not found` even tough I have installed using `luarocks install --local lsqlite3`.

`lsqlite3` has been installed for `5.1` instead of `5.2.` as I can see by this file: `~/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/lsqlite3.so`

How can I make `luarocks` to install the correct version.

error trace:

```
*** lua: save_chat_history.lua:53: module 'lsqlite3' not found:
    no field package.preload['lsqlite3']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lsqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lsqlite3/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lsqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lsqlite3/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/lsqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/lsqlite3/init.lua'
    no file './lsqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lsqlite3.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/lsqlite3.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/lsqlite3.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './lsqlite3.so'
```

I am using `luarocks` installed from apt-get in kubuntu. Shuold I build it from source and use `./configure --lua-version=5.2` ?

Comment: Did building from source work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the LuaRocks from the official repositories only supports Lua 5.1. If you want LuaRocks for a different or even multiple Lua versions, you'll have to install LuaRocks from source.

In addition to `--lua-version=5.2` you might also need `--lua-suffix=5.2` on Ubuntu. The other default values should work ok.